# How to move files whose file name is not used in a set of text files?

Tags: powershell, file-management

I'm a Powershell beginner and this is my first post on stackoverflow. I can understand some simple pipelines, but the following challenge is too complicated for me at this point:

I have a folder with testdata containing *.bmp files and their associated files. I want a powershell script to check which bmp-files are still used. If not used, move bmp-files and associated files to another folder.

Details:

- bmp-files and associated files: For example; car01.bmp, car01.log, car01.file, car02.bmp, (...)
- The bmp-files are in use if their file name (eg, car01.bmp) is mentioned in any of the (text/csv) files in at least one of 2 locations (incl. subfolders).
- If the file name is not found in any of the text files, I want the script to move that file, and any file who's name differs only by file extension to a designated folder.

Looking forward to your solutions!

Comment: Could you please show at least some of your code/attempts?

Comment: `get-childitem -Path .\testdata -Name -Include *.bmp | Where-Object { $_ -ne "test02.bmp" }`
I got stuck here. This returns a list of file names (that could perhaps be used to move the corresponding files) and it includes a simple condition. But I did not find out how to replace that condition with something like 'for each file, check if it's file name occurs in these files. If you find an occurance, go to next file, if not, move the corresponding file).

Comment: I think you first need to think of a way to consolidate the 'InUse' info into one text or csv file. Armed with that is should be a breeze to figure out which files are not mentioned at least twice. Please add details about the text/csv files

Comment: @Domodosola - please, add your code from that comment to your Question. that will let others find it quickly AND make it easier to read. [*grin*]